# Attempt at storing input in an array of type struct with unexpected behavior

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, io

I am trying to make a program that reads a text file. The text file contains numbers representing rgb numbers. An example of test.txt:

```
P3
3 4       
255
12 32 222 12 32 222 12 32 222 12 32 222 12 32 222 12 32 222 12 32 222 
12 32 222 12 32 222 12 32 222 12 32 222 12 32 222
```

Emulating a PPM file. I then ignore the first line, read the following three integers to use in calculations for later. What I have been testing that doesn't behave properly is trying to store the following numbers in an array of struct type RGB that contains three elements of type unsigned char: r, g, b. What I don't understand is that when I try printing the first few elements, my first pixel (first struct, first r,g,b) is correct, then, the next three numbers are random, and every execution after will generate that set with random numbers. The rest are zeros. I though I had my understanding correct, could anyone please help me? Code:

```
#include filter.h
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

RGB *readPPM(const char *file, int *width, int *height, int *max) 

{
width = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);         
height = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
max = malloc(sizeof(int)*3);        

FILE *fp;                               
int numOfPix, i=0;
char garbage[3];                                                        

if ((fp = fopen(file,"r")) == NULL)                                         
{
    printf("No such file exists!");
}

fgets(garbage,sizeof(garbage),fp);                                      
fscanf(fp,"%d %d %d",width,height,max);                             
int numofPix = (*width) * (*height);            
RGB pixels[numOfPix];                                       
RGB *returnptr = pixels;
printf("w: %d h: %d m: %d pix: %d\n",*width,*height,*max,numofPix);
while (!feof(fp))
{
    fscanf(fp,"%hhd %hhd %hhd", &pixels[i].r, &pixels[i].g, &pixels[i].b);
    i++;    
}
fclose(fp);
return returnptr;
}

int main()
{
RGB *RGBValues;
int *width, *height, *max;
int j=0;
char *testfile = "test.txt";
RGBValues = readPPM(testfile,width,height,max); 
for(j=0;j<5;j++)
{
printf("r: %d g: %d b: %d\n",RGBValues[j].r,RGBValues[j].g,RGBValues[j].b);
}
}
```

Structure definition in filter.h:

```
typedef struct { unsigned char r, g, b; } RGB;
```

Sample output:

```
w: 3 h: 4 m: 255 pix: 12        //Correct
r: 12 g: 32 b: 222              //Correct
r: 232 g: 253 b: 85            //Changes every execution
r: 0 g: 0 b: 19                //Static
r: 0 g: 0 b: 0                //Static
r: 0 g: 0 b: 0                  //Static
```

Comment: What happens to the memory pointed to by `return returnptr;` on return? (hint: poof!) and any further attempt to access it invokes *Undefined Behavior*. (you must allocate for the array of struct, not declare local to your function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring pointers `int *width, *height, *max;` and passing them to `readPPM`. Then in `readPPM` you put

```
width = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);         
height = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
max = malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
```

These `malloc` allocations create array of integers for `width`, `height`, `max`. Clearly that is not your intent to create an array for width and height. Don't do any of that. Just declare integers and pass the address.

Also don't use `while(feof(fp))`, check the return value for `fscanf` instead, and break the loop if `fscanf` fails.

As pointed out in comment, `RGB pixels[numOfPix]` is destroyed when the function exits. In this case, do use `malloc` for `RGB *pixels`. This will create memory on heap, it will not be destroyed when the function exits. You will have to free that memory later.

```
RGB *readPPM(const char *file, int *ptr_width, int *ptr_height, int *ptr_max)
{
    int width, height, max;

    FILE *fp;
    int numOfPix, i = 0;
    char garbage[3];

    if((fp = fopen(file, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("No such file exists!");
    }

    fgets(garbage, sizeof(garbage), fp);
    fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d", &width, &height, &max);
    int numofPix = width * height;
    RGB *pixels = malloc(numofPix * sizeof(RGB));
    printf("w: %d h: %d m: %d pix: %d\n", width, height, max, numofPix);
    while(fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d", &pixels[i].r, &pixels[i].g, &pixels[i].b) == 3)
    {
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    *ptr_width = width;
    *ptr_height = height;
    *ptr_max = max;

    return pixels;
}

int main()
{
    RGB *RGBValues;
    int width, height, max;
    int j = 0;
    char *testfile = "test.txt";

    //pass the address of width, height, and max
    RGBValues = readPPM(testfile, &width, &height, &max);
    for(j = 0; j<5; j++)
    {
        printf("r: %d g: %d b: %d\n", RGBValues[j].r, RGBValues[j].g, RGBValues[j].b);
    }

    //width, height, max should be modified:
    printf("%d %d %d\n", width, height, max);

    //free the memory which was allocated in `readPPM`
    free(RGBValues);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the improvements although I am not to sure what was causing the undefined behavior. Was it from the unneeded pointers?

Comment: I am not really sure because I am using Visual Studio, you are probably using gcc. UB is usually not consistent across compilers. The pointer was one problem, another was `RGB pixels[numOfPix]` because that creates memory on "stack" it is destroyed as soon as the function exits.

Comment: By the way, you do need pointers if you want to print the value of `width`, `height` in `main`, but you don't need `malloc` for that. See the part where it sets `*ptr_width = width;` This modifies the value of `width` which was declared in `main`